# iphone UIPickerView select row

Tags: iphone, select, row, uipickerview

I have my view  that contains the UIPickerView...
I tried to make this code:

```
[self.picker selectRow:rowSelected inComponent:0 animated:true];
```

to select the row with index rowSelected, but this doesn't work...
I need to put this in viewdidload??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not call this method yourself.  It is called by the system when a user selects a row in the pickerview.  You should override the implementation of that method to do whatever you wish should happen when the user selects that row in that component.